# How to fix the size of div?

Tags: css, html

Hi i have taken one `<a>` tag and on hover of it one other div opens.
and below  tag i have taken other div which display.
but when I hover mouse on `<a>` tag other div opens but the regular div below the `<a>` tag change it's location and went below. so I want that although on hover of `<a>` tag new div opens the regular div should not change it's position.
The new div should be open or display on existing div.

[jsfiddle Demo for it](http://jsfiddle.net/jXDBN/)

My code :

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Reading Image</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .testtmpblock{
            display: none;
            background-color:black;
            min-height: 100px;
            width: 200px;

        }
        .tmpd{
            height: 100px;
            width: 100px;
            background-color: blue;
        }
        .tt{
            height: 120px;
            width: 100px;
            background-color: fuchsia;
            position: fixed;display: block;
        }
    </style>
    <script src="jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>

        $(document).ready(function () {
      $(document).on('mouseenter', '.cart', function () {


          $(this).next(".testtmpblock").show();
      }).on('mouseleave', '.cart', function () {
          $(this).next(".testtmpblock").hide();
      });
  });


    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="#" class="cart"> Cart </a><div class="testtmpblock"></div>
    <div class="tt">hello</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Any suggestion to do so ?

Comment: You are going to have to `absolute` position the `.testtmpblock` DIV and make sure it has a container with `position: relative;`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set the `position` of the `.testtmpblock` to `absolute`

```
.testtmpblock{
        display: none;
        background-color:black;
        min-height: 100px;
        width: 200px;
        position:absolute;
    }
```

demo at http://jsfiddle.net/jXDBN/2/

Comment: Isn't that too risky? I mean is there any possibility that the div will have undesirable `top` and `left` props if you won't set them manually?

Comment: @matewka, if you do not set them, the element will be positioned to where it would be if it was not `position:absolute`. It follows the flow in terms of positioning, but does not affect the flow of others due to the `position:absolute`. Of course in complex design this might pose problems. In the OP nothing is actually positioned, so i suggested this answer for this scenario..

Comment: Right now I'm reading the w3 documentation and can't find that perticular information. Can you provide any link to the specific paragraph explaining this behaviour?

Comment: @matewka also read http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS_absolute_and_fixed_positioning and search for "*default value for the top*" quoting "***The default value for the `top`, `right`, `bottom` and `left` properties is `auto`, which means the absolutely positioned box will appear exactly where it would have had if it wasn’t positioned***"

Comment: That's also very helpful! I've spent years, wrapping _absolute_ elements inside another just in purpose of setting `position: relative` on the latter to position the former correctly.

Comment: @matewka, if you want to define a position, you need to set a container to `relative` (*as you know*) .. but if you want it to stay *in-place*, **only** then, there is not need..

Answer (score 1):

First, wrap the `.testtmpblock` inside the `<a>` tag:

```
<a href="#" class="cart"> Cart <div class="testtmpblock"></div></a>
<div class="tt">hello</div>
```

Then position this div absolutely:

```
.cart {
    position: relative;
}
.testtmpblock{
    display: none;
    background-color:black;
    min-height: 100px;
    width: 200px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
}
.tt{
    height: 120px;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: fuchsia;
    position: fixed;
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your CSS style according to this...

```
.tt {

height: 120px;

width: 100px;

background-color: fuchsia;

position:fixed;

top:30px;

left:12px;

 }
```

[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Dayv9/)

Comment: That show new div in background otherwise your code also complete.